# How to create a generic for function in Typescript that returns exact type depends on input param?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the next interface `Params`:

```js
interface Params {
  readonly paramA: string;
  readonly paramB: number;
  readonly paramC: readonly string[];
}
```

and code that uses the interface `Params`:

```js
const params : Params = {
  paramA: 'woof',
  paramB: 420,
  paramC: ['bark']
} as const;

getParam(key) {
  return params[key];
}
```

Is it possible to write a generic that will understand what type of value will be returned by calling `getParam` with the exact key? Something like:

```js
getParam<K = keyof Params>(key: K) : typeof Params[K] {
  return params[key];
}

getParam('paramA'); // string
getParam('paramB'); // number
getParam('paramC'); // string[]
```

Comment: This is not a type guard. Anyway, `<K extends keyof Params>(key: K): Params[K]` is what you want

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh, yeah? thanks! Just forgot about the `extends`. How to name it correctly? "Generic"? Also, it would be good to make it like a reply to mark it "resolved".

Comment: In `<T extends U>`, `extends U` is known is as a _generic type constraint_. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, it is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgZ2QbwChlkoI4ATAexABsBPZABw2wEEAuZHMKUAcwDcxUuWp1GLTFgBCXEAFcsAI2jCSZSjQbNWWAMJdN4nTz4h+AbQC6wgL6FCCGj13S8AXgIip7LgHIAdyoqGH8AGh89OWQAFgAmAAZIkl8DLkt-ZQwAa39rQjtkODxnEB5hQhgFEAQwYBpkfggwdGkAHgBpZAgAD0gQCjwciHpQtD0cAD4AChH6Lk6ASi427BxLTutvDRaFKBA3dct520LHZta9Gf80tn8lwWQAemfuXgFCS7WsG7SZB5PV7IRQqaBfFo-P56fSAl5vYzaRhmAQ2RxVGp1BqHb56eJdHr9CCDYajcZgehMCDjNLTOajRYrZAzClUmmTJabbZEXZgfaHWknUZnBwQq7SeLQ6T3R7w5AAImCoXlYp+ktu0ThwISiVVeKl2FhsuBlnl2SgOXlBSAA)

As Aluan said, this is what you want:

```
function getParam<K extends keyof Params>(key: K): Params[K] {
  return params[key];
}

getParam('paramA'); // string
getParam('paramB'); // number
getParam('paramC'); // readonly string[]
```

---

You can even go a step further and have it know the actual values:

```
const params = {
  paramA: 'woof',
  paramB: 420,
  paramC: ['bark']
} as const;

function getParam2<K extends keyof typeof params>(key: K): (typeof params)[K] {
  return params[key];
}

getParam2('paramA'); // "woof"
getParam2('paramB'); // 420
getParam2('paramC'); // ["bark"]
```